# View Dismissing itself on touch without any code

Tags: ios

I have a series of view controllers that are navigated by "Back" and "Next" UIBarButtonItems*. The Problem I have is the view controllers dismiss when the view is touched anywhere in the top half of the view without any code whatsoever.

Nothing is calling **[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];** I didn't notice this behavior until after I updated to xcode 6.3.1  I can't even think of a way to capture the event with NSLog.

I have commented out everything but the view still dismisses when I touch 
it. I've never been stumped like this. **Any suggestions**?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  //  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actNext:)];
  //  swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
  //  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

 //   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actBack:)];
 //   swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
 //  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)actNext:(id)sender
{
    //PageThree *p3 = [[PageThree alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageThree" bundle:nil];
    //[p3 setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    //[self presentViewController:p3 animated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(IBAction)actBack:(id)sender
{

    NSLog (@"Dismiss Invoked");
   // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard segue and autolayout?

Comment: What happens if you set view.UserInteractionEnabled = NO?

Comment: @ArunGupta The First View is Main.storyboard but I leave the storyboard and build out with view controllers and xibs. I don't use auto layout.

Comment: @Teddy   When I set userInteractionEnabled to NO, the problem does not occur But it renders the view useless as any buttons or TextFields are not  accessible.

Comment: How many views are added to self.view. Give each of them a different color and see which view is causing this. Also is it a UINavigation in your application. This is a weird problem and may happen when you upgrade XCode.

Comment: @Mick: so that means that you have an underlying gesture recogniser on the parent view. Also consider Arun's comment so make all views different color and semi transparent so you will recognise easily where is your tap captured.

Comment: Thanks. You may be onto something there.  Originally I did have a gesture recognizer on the parent view but Deleted it before I noticed the problem. I have Cleaned a few times but maybe that deleted gesture recognizer is hiding out somewhere.  I'll explore that avenue.